# как создать список из имеющихся елементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Как можно сделать список из имеющихся елементов

<div class="block">
   <div class="item">1</div>
   <div class="item">2</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">6</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
   <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

чтобы в результате вышло так, если елементы вдруг поменялись там по какомунить событию оно снова прошло по всем блокам сразу 1, 2 а потом 3 и снова выстроило елементы

```
<div class="result">
    <div class="result-item">1</div>
    <div class="result-item">2</div>
    <div class="result-item">4</div>
    <div class="result-item">3</div>
    <div class="result-item">6</div>
    <div class="result-item">4</div>
    <div class="result-item">6</div>
    <div class="result-item">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  function addItems() {
    var $result = $('.result');
    $result.html('');

    $.each($('.item'), function(index, val) {
      $result.append($(val).clone());
    });
  }

  addItems();
});
```

```css
.result {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```